# How to traverse through a map to create resources

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am using Terraform v0.14.10
I am looking to create a few resources in a dynamic way based on a deployment map,

From a local vars output like this,

```
+ server_module_outputs = {
      + list_env_groups = [
          + {
              + "grp1" = {
                  + envs = [
                      + "stg-a1",
                      + "stg-b1",
                    ]
                  + host = [
                      + "example.co.uk",
                    ]
                }
              + "grp2" = {
                  + envs = [
                      + "stg-e1",
                      + "stg-f1",
                    ]
                  + host = [
                      + "example.co.uk",
                    ]
                }
            },
          + {
              + "grp1" = {
                  + envs = [
                      + "stg-a2",
                      + "stg-b2",
                    ]
                  + host = [
                      + "example.com",
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
      + list_envs       = [
          + "stg-a1",
          + "stg-b1",
          + "stg-e1",
          + "stg-f1",
          + "stg-a2",
          + "stg-b2",
        ]
      + list_zones      = [
          + "eu-west2-c",
          + "us-east1-a",
        ]
    }
```

I would like to create environments (stg-a1, stg-b1…) like this and link to the respective group (grp1, grp2) based on the list_env_groups list using a local-exec, something like this,

```
resource "google_apigee_environment" "apigee" {
  for_each =  local.list_env_groups (don't know what to put here)
  name         = each.value // would like to pass grp1 or grp2

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = create
    command = <<EOF
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer ${data.google_client_config.current.access_token}"\
  "https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/envgroups/***${respective_group}***/attachments" \
  -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" \
  -d '{"environment":"****current_environment****"}'
EOF
  }
  
}
```

Please see the **<respective_group>** and the **<current_environment>** in the curl to know how I want to link the group and environment

As you can see above local.list_envs is only containing the env names. I know I need to traverse the other list (list_env_groups) to get the relationship between an environment and a group.

I only require help with the terraform configuration language of “for_each” and “for” syntaxes, I know the resource creation and the local-exec works, so that’s fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would be the transformed version of the map?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I don't want to transform the map. Let me edit the question and ask a smaller question.